# Run button in android studio is disabled and gradle pane display "Nothing to show"

Tags: android, gradle

I am using Android studio v3.6.3 , I see the run button has been disabled. And I could see there was nothing in the Gradle pane it displays " Nothing to show". 
I was confused . So I deleted the old gradle folder (v6.2.2) downloaded the latest version and imported it. In the terminal bar it shows 1 process running, when I click open it , it shows gradle all 5.6.4 downloading . But later sometime it fails.

Please help

Comment: is there any emulator or device that using in project? check it out

Comment: No everything on that side is disabled

Comment: Did you run project from correct path? Would you add screenshot of whole Android Studio window?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ne9A1GSZ2fSP9bne-JqERyBkA498zn9a/view?usp=sharing       here is my screenshots file. If you want more to be added for clearer references please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: the project has been saved in gradle folder. If it is wrong , tell me which is correct folder to save the project

Answer (score 0):

Caused by : org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ResolveException:Could not resolve al artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

This was the error popped up when I sync the project